# A Windows application can't load a DLL library

Tags: dll, windows-10, loadlibrary

I have two computers (x64, Windows 10 PRO). I run an application on the first computer. At one point of the execution, the process loads a third party DLL file (call it xyz.dll). Everything works. Then I run the SAME application on the second computer. At one point, the app tries to load xyz.dll. It fails with a message saying "Library not found". I ran the debugger and the error code is 126. Here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Debug/system-error-codes--0-499 it means "The specified module could not be found".

Can you help me to find the cause?

More infos:

- I made sure that the xyz.dll is unique on the computer so the app can't 
     take another copy.
- I used the exactly the same installer on both computer.
- I have the source code of the app and LoadLibray is used 
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx 
     with the full path of the dll. No mistake in the path.
- I have the source code and I looked into it. The name of the xyz.dll is 
     harcoded so there is no configuration issue here.
- I don't have the source code of xyz.dll.

Well, many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I ran Dependency Walker and I found that one library on which xyz.dll depends was not present on the second computer.